# How to detect when UITextField's inputview opened?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have set a custom `UIDatePicker` to `UITextField`. I can detect when it closes, because I have "Done" button in there. How can I detect when it's opened? I want to make screen darker while user is selecting.

Answer (score 6):

This relies on the UITextFieldDelegate to determine when the textfield becomes active. The key to this working in your situation is to check the `inputView` of your `textField` to see if it matches the `pickerView` you are using. Ideally, the only change you will need to make is to replace the name of the `pickerView` variable I used.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.inputView == pickerView {
        // Do your thing here
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other way to detect this?